# Find the associated vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, vector-fields

> Consider the map $\hat{G}_{s} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & cos(s)
>  & sin(s)\\ 0 & -sin(s) & cos(s) \end{pmatrix} : \mathbb{R}^3 \to
>  \mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> 1. Prove that $\hat{G}_s$ induces a diffeomorphism $G_s
>     : S^2 \to S^2$ and show that this defines a flow $G$ on $S^2$.
> 2. Find
>    the associated vector field $\zeta ^G$ and find the points where
>    $\zeta ^G$ is zero.

Question 1 is fine, my problem is with Question 2. My attempt:

The associated vector field is $\zeta ^G : S^2 \to TS^2, (x,y,z) \mapsto [\sigma _x]$, where $\sigma_{x}(t) = G_t (x)$. Since $G$ is a flow on $S^2$ we have $\sigma_{x}(0) = G_0 (x) = x$. Now we need to find where $\zeta ^G$ is $0$. i.e. the set $Z$:

$$ Z = \{(x,y,z) \in S^2 : [\sigma _x] = 0\} = \{(x,y,z) \in S^2 : D\sigma_x |_0 = 0 \} \tag{1}$$
and we can calculate $$ D\sigma_x |_0 = (0,z,-y)$$ So
$$ Z = \{(x,y,z) \in S^2 : (0,z,-y)=0 \}$$, i.e. the x-axis.

My attempt is apparently incorrect and I have no idea why. My questions:

1. Where have I gone wrong?

2. Is the equality in (1) true? I think it is because there exists a bijection between $T_x X$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong? The map is a rotation around X, so it is natural that the vector would be zero on the rotation axis.

Comment: @blamocur The solution seemed to indicate otherwise, but actually now I think it may just be a very poorly explained solution. Thanks.